# angucomplete-alt Search with Begins than Contains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, custom-search-provider

I am using angucomplete-alt for auto-populating the data for a search box. It shows all the records which contains the given value, even the given value is in the middle of the string. I want to populate the records which starts with the given text. Is there any way to do that?

thanks in advance...